# Algolia: How to use secured_api_key in client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I'm following these instructions:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/how-to/how-to-restrict-the-search-to-a-subset-of-records-belonging-to-a-specific-user/?language=ruby

on how to create a `secured_api_key`:

```
secured_api_key = Algolia.generate_secured_api_key(
  'your_search_only_api_key_kept_private', # Make sure to use a search key
  { filters: 'viewable_by:' + current_user_id.to_s }
)
```

Where and how do I use this secured_api_key (generated in Ruby) in Javascript to have results pre-filtered? I’m using the React Autocomplete widget.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the secured API Key to your client. Here is two alternatives:

1. Expose a route that returns the API Key. The client call has to perform an XHR request to have access to it. Once you have the key you can instantiate the client and the React application.
2. You can inline the API Key within the HTML within a JavaScript object. This pattern is usually done to SSR React application. Once the application starts you grab the "global" value. You can find a guide within the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/api-keys-security/js/#secured-api-keys) that describes this pattern.